# How to receive JSON data in Dictionary using FromData in Web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, dictionary, asp.net-web-api

Below is JSON example which client will send to my API named as 'GetQuestion'

```
 {
                 "lstQuestions": [{
                    "QuestionCategory": 1,
                    "QuestionText": "what is m in mvc",
                    "OptionA": "model",
                     "OptionB": "view", 
                     "OptionC": "controller", 
                     "OptionD": "razor",
                    "CorrectOption": "A"
                },
                {
                    "QuestionCategory": 2,
                    "QuestionText": "How are you",
                    "OptionA": "fine",
                     "OptionB": "not fine", 
                     "OptionC": "ok", 
                     "OptionD": "not ok",
                    "CorrectOption": "A"
                }],
               "Status" : 1

          }
```

Below is my controller API code:

```
 public class QuestionDetails
    {
        public List<Questions> lstQuestions { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
    }
    public class Questions
    {
        public string QuestionCategory { get; set; }
        public string QuestionText { get; set; }
        public string OptionA { get; set; }
        public string OptionB { get; set; }
        public string OptionC { get; set; }
        public string OptionD { get; set; }
        public string CorrectOption { get; set; }

    }

    [Route("GetQuestions")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage SendQuestionDetails([FromBody] QuestionDetails UserDetailInput)
    {

        HttpResponseMessage mesage = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Demo"); ;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //in progress
        }
        return mesage;

    }
```

What I want to do is how to create a class with Dictionary and pass as parameter, I don't want to use List because its heavy and Dictionary is much faster than List.

For example:

```
  public class QuestionDetails
    {
        public Dictionary<string, Questions> lstQuestions { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
    } 
public HttpResponseMessage SendQuestionDetails([FromBody] Dictionary<string, QuestionDetails> UserDetailInput)
    {

        HttpResponseMessage mesage = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Demo"); ;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //in progress
        }
        return mesage;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what are you talking about with Dictionary is much faster than List but you just need to send the JSON as

```
{
    "A": {
        "lstQuestions": {
            "A": {
                "QuestionCategory": 1,
                "QuestionText": "what is m in mvc",
                "OptionA": "model",
                "OptionB": "view",
                "OptionC": "controller",
                "OptionD": "razor",
                "CorrectOption": "A"
            },
            "V": {
                "QuestionCategory": 2,
                "QuestionText": "How are you",
                "OptionA": "fine",
                "OptionB": "not fine",
                "OptionC": "ok",
                "OptionD": "not ok",
                "CorrectOption": "A"
            }
        },
        "Status": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not passing the data . Third party is sending me JSON , i cannot modify the data. My question is regarding C# not JSON . how do use Dictionary rather than List ?

Comment: @Nik Well then you question makes no sense. What do you plan to use as a key in the dictionary? If you use the index in the array you are just creating a simple array and all operations are much slower with dictionaries then memory arrays.

Answer (score -1):

Hope below code will clear your query.

```
   public HttpResponseMessage SendQuestionDetails([FromBody] Dictionary<string, QuestionDetails> UserDetailInput)
        {
   List<Questions> list = new List<Questions> { };
            list.Add(new Questions
            {
                CorrectOption = "CorrectOption1",
                OptionA = "OptionA1",
                OptionB = "OptionB1",
                OptionC = "OptionC1",
                OptionD = "OptionD1",
                QuestionCategory = "QuestionCategory1",
                QuestionText = "QuestionText1"
            });
            list.Add(new Questions
            {
                CorrectOption = "CorrectOption2",
                OptionA = "OptionA2",
                OptionB = "OptionB2",
                OptionC = "OptionC2",
                OptionD = "OptionD2",
                QuestionCategory = "QuestionCategory2",
                QuestionText = "QuestionText2"
            });

            Dictionary<QuestionDetails, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<QuestionDetails, int> { };
            QuestionDetails detail = new QuestionDetails { lstQuestions = list, Status = 1 };

            HttpResponseMessage mesage = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, detail);
            return mesage;
    return mesage;
    }
```

Comment: Don't understand what did you try to do here?

Comment: Just provide the code which return the json format you want.

Comment: His question is bad but you answer just returns a detail object and `Dictionary<QuestionDetails, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<QuestionDetails, int> { };` Never used.

Comment: Bro that's way to coding and it's my style.